# Make a partition with only Windows 8.1 in it. Already installed. And move it to SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, windows-8.1

I just bought a SSD and would like to migrate the OS from HDD to SSD. I tried easeUS Partition Manager but it says that the disk (120gb) isn't big enough.

I think the problem is that I don't have a specific partition for Windows. It's all in the same Partition of 532gb, maximum 931gb.

I would just like to move OS to SSD but I am not sure how. If not possible. Should I reinstall windows on SSD?

Comment: You could reinstall on the SSD.  Or you could use a program like Acronis.

Comment: Thanks. You mean Acronis Disk Director 12?

Comment: no I was thinking more along the lines of Acronis True Image 2014.  It will allow you to backup the drive as an image file.  Then restore to the SSD using the same image file.

Comment: You could also use [**Todo Backup Free**](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm).

Comment: [**Todo Backup Free Tutorial**](http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows)

Comment: Use `Paragon Hard Disk Manager`, it can transfer your whole OS to another drive. http://www.paragon-software.com/nl/home/hdm-personal/

Comment: Is there less than 120GB of stuff on the bigger drive?

Comment: The smaller, SSD drive, which I like to copy the os to is 120GB. The large, current HDD is 1TB

Comment: Yes, and how much space is used on that 1TB drive?